# Disk convexity and triangle inaqulity - geometric reasoning

Tags: geometry

The fact is absolutely obvious when targeting it analytically but I'm sure this should be somewhat very easy to see geometrically from triangles in R^2. Something like the segment from vertex to the opposite side is less than largest of the vertex's sides. But it also requires some proof. Stuked with this :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof of what you want here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Ball_is_Convex_Set

Comment: Not exactly as it's the same analytic proof. I mean it's seems obvious that the segment connecting vertex and opposite side of a triangle must be less than the largest side. I expect it to follow from the triangle inequality in some very simple way with no stuff like convexity etc

Answer (score 0):

I think the reasoning could be like this. We can stick to "middlepoint" convexity. Having a equal-sides triangle (equal sides are radiuses of the disk we want to be convex) we want to prove that the median is less than the side (radius), i.e. $\frac{|a + b|}{2} <= |a|$ ($|a| = |b| = r$). This is equivalent to triangle inequality. It seems to me that it works.